# Link relation type for linking representations to the abstract resource?

Tags: http-headers, uri, rel, content-negotiation

I use [Content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) to let user-agents select one of several representations for a resource.

**Example**: the resource `http://example.com/essay` has the following representations:

- `text/html` → `http://example.com/essay.html`
- `application/xhtml+xml` → `http://example.com/essay.xhtml`
- `application/pdf` → `http://example.com/essay.pdf`

Let’s say the user-agent selects the HTML variant. Now I could link the other representations with the [link relation type `alternate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-alternate):

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/xhtml+xml" href="/essay.xhtml">
<link rel="alternate" type="application/pdf" href="/essay.pdf">
```

But when someone only has the URI `http://example.com/essay.html`, how would he ever know that the content-type neutral URI is `http://example.com/essay`, e.g. for sending someone the link without enforcing that he’d want to see the HTML variant, too?

**Is there a link type to link back to the "abstract" resource (`http://example.com/essay`)?**

I can’t use the [`alternate` link relation type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-alternate) for that link too, as the resource has no content type:

> If the `alternate` keyword is used with the `type` attribute, it indicates that the referenced document is a reformulation of the current document in the specified format.

I don’t think that the [`canonical` link relation type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596) is appropriate here. It would work in some cases, but maybe I want the HTML variant to be the canonical one (for indexing by search engines etc.). When I’d make `http://example.com/essay` the canonical one, search engines could (in principle) use the PDF variant for indexing.

Comment: What would be the harm if a search engine did decide to use the PDF for indexing? Presumably the content is identical.

Comment: @nilskp: Even if the content would be the same, the semantic information would differ (think of WAI-ARIA, RDFa, metadata). Also the HTML variant might include user comments. Despite that, some formats are more user-friendly, some are intended for machines, some formats aren’t support by all/most user-agents, etc.

Comment: Is there a reason for even specifying content-type specific resources? Couldn't you do content negotiation at the resource level, i.e. there only `http://example.com/essay` exists and the content type is determined per access?

Comment: @nilskp: I think it’s more user-friendly to be able to link to a specific content type. Example: some tools might not send the `Accept` header, so you need to feed them the appropriate content type manually. Another example: a link »On `/essay` you’ll find user comments«, but the user-agent might fetch the PDF variant (without any comments).