# Linked data: getting real data (from e.g. /page to /resource)

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia

**A 303 problem:**

How can I get the URI `/resource` from the human-readable `/page` (e.g., `dbpedia.org/page/Salzburg`). When a user browses to `/page`, I want to show him the RDF data from `/resource` (by clicking on a JS bookmarklet) AND only this resource.  Possibilities:

1. `foaf:primarytopic`
2. `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#alternate`

On DBpedia it works just fine with `foaf:primarytopic`, but data from http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/2014 will show this alternate URI: http://data.linkedmdb.org/data/film/2014 (and no `foaf:primarytopic`).

Data from `http://data.linkedmdb.org/data/film/2014` is a graph within which is an id,  `http://data.linkedmdb.org/data/film/2014`, where the `foaf:primarytopic` is the URI that is needed: `http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/2014`. See

http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/convert/detect/json-ld/http://data.linkedmdb.org/data/film/2014

for the data.  There will be three HTTP requests (1. `/page` 2. `/data` 3. `/resource`) How is it possible to get the ‘real’ data about a resource faster?

Comment: If I do understand you right, you search for a way to find the resource URI (`/resource/Salzburg`) when you are on a page *about* this thing (`/page/Salzburg` or `/data/Salzburg.n3`)? I think I have a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16443030/1591669) (however, my question is not only about the Linked Data, but more general).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question. In linked data, it's generally held to be good practice to distinguish between the **identity** of the thing itself - a film, a city, a bathing water, etc - and a **description** of that that resource in some notation. Not least, this is because you can then make claims about the description distinct from claims about the actual resource - for example when it was most recently updated.

Depending on the form of the description you request, you'll get back a different representation of the identified resource. So, to take your example film, if we request the HTML presentation we get one encoding:

```
$ wget -O /dev/null -H http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/2014
Resolving data.linkedmdb.org (data.linkedmdb.org)... 128.100.1.11
Connecting to data.linkedmdb.org (data.linkedmdb.org)|128.100.1.11|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 303 See Other
Location: http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/2014 [following]
--2013-05-28 13:58:26--  http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/film/2014
Reusing existing connection to data.linkedmdb.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `/dev/null'
    [  <=>                                                      ] 39,627       163K/s   in 0.2s    
2013-05-28 13:58:26 (163 KB/s) - `/dev/null' saved [39627]
```

But if we request a description in a data format, such as RDF/XML, we get a different result:

```
$ wget -O /dev/null --header="Accept: application/rdf+xml" -H http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/2014
Resolving data.linkedmdb.org (data.linkedmdb.org)... 128.100.1.11
Connecting to data.linkedmdb.org (data.linkedmdb.org)|128.100.1.11|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 303 See Other
Location: http://data.linkedmdb.org/data/film/2014 [following]
--2013-05-28 13:59:32--  http://data.linkedmdb.org/data/film/2014
Reusing existing connection to data.linkedmdb.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/rdf+xml]
Saving to: `/dev/null'
    [ <=>                                                       ] 11,501      --.-K/s   in 0.1s    
2013-05-28 13:59:33 (95.9 KB/s) - `/dev/null' saved [11501]
```

So the requesting agent can get from the identity of the resource `.../resource/film/2014` to the HTML presentation `.../page/film/2014` or to the RDF description `.../resource/data/2014` in a single redirection.

Note that you don't *have* to provide different URLs for the different cases. In the UK bathing waters dataset, we distinguish between resource identities `.../id/..` and resource descriptions `.../doc/...`. There isn't a different URL for the HTML, JSON or RDF/XML encodings - it just depends what content encoding the requestor asks for. [Note: this isn't strictly true, in that you can append `.json`, `.ttl`, etc, to the end of the `../doc/..` URL to get the different encodings, but that's just a user convenience rather than a fundamental difference between the URL's of page and data representations]

Example:

```
$ wget -O - -H --header="Accept: text/turtle" http://environment.data.gov.uk/id/bathing-water/ukc2102-03600
--2013-05-28 14:10:39--  http://environment.data.gov.uk/id/bathing-water/ukc2102-03600
Resolving environment.data.gov.uk (environment.data.gov.uk)... 46.137.33.70, 54.216.25.150
Connecting to environment.data.gov.uk (environment.data.gov.uk)|46.137.33.70|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 303 See Other
Location: /doc/bathing-water/ukc2102-03600 [following]
--2013-05-28 14:10:39--  http://environment.data.gov.uk/doc/bathing-water/ukc2102-03600
Reusing existing connection to environment.data.gov.uk:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6351 (6.2K) [text/turtle]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

...
 bw:ukc2102-03600
      a       def-bw:CoastalBathingWater , def-bw:BathingWater ;
      def-bwp:latestBathingWaterProfile
```

So I *think* you are asking if it's necessary to read the HTML page to get the links to the data about a resource from its identity. If so, the answer is no, you don't. It can be confusing using only a web browser to look at linked data resources, as the browser doesn't really give you a way of requesting other representations than HTML. I'd advise getting familiar with `wget` or `curl` on the command line. They should be available already on Linux or MacOs systems; on Windows you can instally cygwin to get a decent command line! Also, reading up on HTTP headers may be helpful.

Comment: i currently work on a (full client-side) javascript bookmarklet and need the reverse direction to get the data i need to display, i know about the requests you can make with accept-header (i actually do that) but i wanna try to make a resource more browsable by only clicking on an bookmark and then automatically change the view..

i am always getting the data with `Accept: application/rdf+xml` but what if is not the real 'thing' and the user is only browsing an html represenation of the data, i will only have the /page URI and need to find out where the real data is.

Comment: it's really difficult for me to explain the problem, and i hope you can understand what i mean.

Comment: OK, I think I understand. I'm not sure there is a way to always achieve that, if the pages the user is browsing are not under your control. If they are your pages, you could embed a `<link rel='canonical' href='...' />` into the page header. Otherwise, I guess you're just going to have to build up a library of patterns for scraping the data URI from a particular HTML representation. Which is icky, but I don't see many alternatives. I suppose you could have a web service that suggested a data URI pattern given an HTML page URL, so at least it's a bit encapsulated.